# converting DO loop into NestList form

Tags: programming

I would like to rewrite this `Do` loop using `NestList`. Can you help me?

**  DO loop

```
Clear[T, A, CC, II, Y, z, a, b, d, e, m, n];

T = 3;
{A[0] = 2, CC[0] = 2, II[0] = 0.5, Y[0] = 5};
{z = 0.3, a = 0.2, b = 3, d = 0.6, e = 0.95, m = 0.2, n = 0.4};

Do[{
  A[t] = (1 + z) A[t - 1],
  R[t] = a A[t] CC[t - 1],
  II[t] = (1 + m) II[t - 1],
  Y[t] = (1 + n) Y[t - 1],
  K[t] = Sqrt[b] R[t],
  K[t + 1] = (1 - a) K[t] + II[t],
  CC[t] = d (Y[t] - K[t + 1]),
  U[t] = e Log[CC[t]]}, {t, 1, T}]

Table[{A[t], R[t], K[t], II[t], Y[t], CC[t], U[t]}, {t, 1, T}]
```

********NESTLIST

```
Clear[A, CC, II, Y, z, a, b, d, e, m, n];

{A[0] = 2, CC[0] = 2, II[0] = 0.5, Y[0] = 5};
{z = 0.3, a = 0.2, b = 3, d = 0.6, e = 0.95, m = 0.2, n = 0.4};

model[{II[t_], Y[t_]}] := 
 With[{z = 0.3, a = 0.2, b = 3, d = 0.6, e = 0.95, m = 0.2, n = 0.4},
  {A[t] = (1 + z) A[t - 1],
   R[t] = a A[t] CC[t - 1],
   II[t] = (1 + m) II[t - 1],
   Y[t] = (1 + n) Y[t - 1],
   K[t] = Sqrt[b] R[t],
   K[t + 1] = (1 - a) K[t] + II[t],
   CC[t] = d (Y[t] - K[t + 1]),
   U[t] = e Log[CC[t]]}
  ]

NestList[model, {2, 10}, T]
```

Answer (score 1):

"Do" form, but I don't think you understand how to use semicolon instead of comma,
even though your semicolon versus comma issues have been corrected a couple of times in
other forums.

```
Clear[T, A, CC, II, Y, z, a, b, d, e, m, n];
T = 3; A[0] = 2; CC[0] = 2; II[0] = 0.5; 
Y[0] = 5; z = 0.3; a = 0.2; b = 3; d = 0.6; e = 0.95; m = 0.2; n = 0.4;
Do[{A[t] = (1 + z) A[t - 1],
  R[t] = a A[t] CC[t - 1],
  II[t] = (1 + m) II[t - 1],
  Y[t] = (1 + n) Y[t - 1],
  K[t] = Sqrt[b] R[t],
  K[t + 1] = (1 - a) K[t] + II[t],
  CC[t] = d (Y[t] - K[t + 1]),
  U[t] = e Log[CC[t]]}, {t, 1, T}];
Table[{A[t], R[t], K[t], II[t], Y[t], CC[t], U[t]}, {t, 1, T}]

(* And the result is
   {{2.6, 1.04, 1.80133, 0.6, 7., 2.97536, 1.03585},
    {3.38, 2.01134, 3.48375, 0.72, 9.8, 3.7758, 1.26218},
    {4.394, 3.31817, 5.74724, 0.864, 13.72, 4.95492, 1.52036}}
*)

(* NestList form, written in an odd style, but trying to help you understand this *)
(* Be VERY careful with this, there are a lot of half-hidden dependencies in this *)
(* I tried to not completely reorganize your original code when I did this *)
T = 3; z = 0.3; a = 0.2; b = 3; d = 0.6; e = 0.95; m = 0.2; n = 0.4;
Rest[
  NestList[{{A, R, K, II, Y, CC, U} = #;
    A = (1 + z) A,
    R = a A CC,
    K = Sqrt[b] a A CC,
    II = (1 + m) II,
    Y = (1 + n) Y,
    CC = d (Y - ((1 - a) K + II)),
    e Log[CC]} &, {2, Null, Null, 0.5, 5, 2, Null}, T]]

(* And the result is
   {{2.6, 1.04, 1.80133, 0.6, 7., 2.97536, 1.03585},
    {3.38, 2.01134, 3.48375, 0.72, 9.8, 3.7758, 1.26218},
    {4.394, 3.31817, 5.74724, 0.864, 13.72, 4.95492, 1.52036}}
*)
```

The idea is you write an initial vector and a function that takes a vector to the next vector.

Comment: Thanks Bill for the answer. I still do not understand what you mean with (;) versus ("space") issue. What is this issue about?

Comment: I know. Semicolons separate statements. Commas separate items in a list. Semicolons do NOT serve exactly the same purpose as in other languages. Yes there is lots of fuzz and ambiguity in Mathematica. Yes you can put statements inside a list and separate them by commas, as you have been doing. In the "function" I built to transform your vector in DestList that was exactly what I did. But by doing that in general you are almost certainly going to let others know that you don't know a lot or have much experience with Mathematica by doing that.

Comment: Bill, I understand you now; but I just followed several  examples given in the documentation of Mathematica. I never saw any NestList Code in the way you introduced. Your way is much simpler and iterating the system quickly. quicker

Comment: That "DestList" I wrote an inch above this should have been NestList, but it is too late to change now. Next, I would be interested in seeing exactly what examples you followed in the documentation to come up with the code and style you used. If you can find that again then please let me know. That might help me understand your question better.

Comment: I noticed the typo "DestList", which I corrected it while writing the model. Basic example, which is, I wi

Comment: It was not a typo in my code, I always repeatedly verify my code works before posting it. The typo was in the comment I wrote, but an error of mine none the less.

Comment: Yes, your Code was correct, only in your description there was a misspelling...another example from the Mathematica documentation is With[{fp = f'}, FixedPoint[# - f[#]/fp[#] &, x0]] and also I followed the guidance from the answers from other platforms. Your method seems the most efficient so far. I used the same structure as yours in iterating a general equilibrium model. It just perfectly works...Your code work if the model is first-difference. Do you have any experience in solving a system of equations with higher-order difference equations?

Comment: To use NestList with a second-difference system the intial vector is the {2,1} iterations. The function uses the {n+1,n} iteration to produce the {n+2,n+1} iteration. For higher order use this same idea. This is becoming a discussion and must stop now.

Comment: I understand...Thank you.